# Take a screenshot of an "invisible" webpage

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, screenshot

I have to write some javascript code to take screenshots of a webpage but without rendering it in the foreground.First of all is it possible?Do I need to use some external libraries?Please give me some ideas :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take Screenshot of Browser via JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316193/take-screenshot-of-browser-via-javascript)

Comment: It's similar but the use case is different. Specifically, that guy needed a snapshot of the current state for support purposes, whereas this question is more about a preview screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking of doing it in Firefox chrome code (i.e. extensions/addons) there's a [really easy way to do it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/drawing_graphics_with_canvas#Rendering_Web_Content_Into_A_Canvas). If you're talking about content code (i.e. webpages) you can do it as above but you have to ask permission first (i.e. `netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');`).

Comment: Thank you thank thank you very much.That's all I wanted.Accepted answer:)

Answer (score 1):

What is this screenshot for? Depending on your needs you can do it directly on the server using one of these libraries:

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

Comment: I will give a link to the script and screenshot a page.Without opening a browser.Does it export only to pdf?

Comment: I'm not sure if those libraries support any formats besides pdf, but you can use ImageMagick to convert pdf to jpg or png.

Comment: Ok, the file format of the screenshot is minor.I want to find a way to take it first. :)

Answer (score -3):

The only way to do it is via ActiveX, which of course only works on IE. See this SO question for examples of this:
[Take a screenshot of a webpage with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

Comment: I need to do it with firefox.Only ActiveX ?:(